# Is it possible to create compatible .aar and .a from Xamarin

Tags: xamarin

The official document has many tutorials about how to use existing Android and IOS libraries, but I can file document about generate .aar and .a, is it possible to write shared library for `non-xamarin` Android and IOS project ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.  Native Android and iOS projects cannot consume Xamarin libraries.